# Cannot change text DPI setting in Windows 7 starter

Tags: windows-7, display-settings

Windows 7 starter came pre-installed on my netbook.  I want to reduce the text DPI setting from Medium (125%) to Smaller (100%) so that certain windows will fully fit on the screen.

I have gone to the Control Panel, Display and tried changing this using the "Smaller" radio button as well as the "Set Custom Text Size (DPI)" screen.  In both cases I apply the change and then log off, as requested.

However when I log in again, the font size remains as Medium, it is still selected and active when I return to the Display screen.  I have also tried a proper reboot after applying the change, no difference.

Is this just one more stupid restriction specific to Windows 7 starter, or am I missing something?

(Upgrading Win7 is simply not an option for me at present.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, according the [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller), DPI scaling `"Applies to all editions of Windows 7"` - so I believe it *should* be possible to do this.

You could try changing the DPI setting directly in the registry.
Instructions are taken from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/443-dpi-display-size-settings-change.html) (option 2), but in summary:

- Open `RegEdit` and find
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI`
- Modify the `LogPixels` value. Specifically, edit it as a **decimal** value, and use one of the "normal" scaling values to avoid problems:

  - Small (100%) = 96
  - Medium (125%) = 120
  - Larger (150%) = 144

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new account in the user setting, the new account will function properly in terms of the DPI setting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem caused by the application Personalization Panel, which keeps the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels locked. After uninstalling Personalization Panel and Personalization Panel DWM Controller the DPI can be changed. After DPI setting you have to reinstall Personalization Panel if you wanna have custom background image in Windows 7 Starter.